# How Vopenka's principle implies Semi-Weak Vopenkas principle?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let's consider 2 large cardinal axioms, the Vopenka's principle (VP)
which says that Ord cannot be fully embedded into Graphs **and**
SWVP which says, that the equivalence $Hom(G(\alpha),G(\alpha'))=\emptyset\Leftrightarrow \alpha<\alpha'$ doesn't hold for any sequence (indexed by Ord) of graphs:

$$\langle G(\alpha) | \alpha\in \text{Ord}\rangle$$

My question is, how can I see that VP implies SWVP as noted [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00284.pdf)?

Comment: The paper you linked gives a reference to "On injectivity in locally presentable categories." for the claim you're interested in, observation 1.12 and theorem 1.9 of the Adamek-Rosicky paper are what you're looking for

Comment: VP is traditionally stated as "Given a class of structures in a fixed signature, one of them elementarily embed into another", and we can replace "fixed signature" by "binary relation", i.e. graphs. Is it clear now why VP implies SWVP?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's not clear to me yet. I would say that the embedding from $\text{Ord}$ into Gra will give us these $G$'s : $$\langle G(\alpha) | \alpha\in \text{Ord}\rangle$$ with Hom as in the OQ, but still I cannot see all the details ...

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Unfortunately I even cannot see why their proof of 1.9 gives us that VP $\Rightarrow$ SWVP though I've searched the reference from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that SWVP fails, as witnessed by a sequence of graphs $\langle \langle G_\alpha; E_\alpha \rangle : \alpha < \text{Ord}\rangle$ such that for all $\alpha, \beta \in \text{Ord}$ there is a homomorphism $\langle G_\alpha; E_\alpha\rangle \to \langle G_\beta; E_\beta\rangle$ if and only if $\alpha \ge \beta$.

Note that the cardinalities of the graphs must be unbounded: otherwise there would be two isomorphic graphs on the sequence.  So by thinning the sequence, we may assume that the cardinality of $G_\alpha$ is a strictly increasing function of $\alpha$.

Then letting $A_\alpha = \{\langle x,y \rangle \in G_\alpha \times G_\alpha : x \ne y\}$ and letting $B_\alpha$ be a rigid binary relation on $G_\alpha$, the sequence $\langle\langle G_\alpha; E_\alpha, A_\alpha, B_\alpha\rangle : \alpha \in \text{Ord}\rangle$ is a counterexample to VP.

Alternatively, the implication from VP to SWVP becomes trivial using the following equivalent form of VP: given any sequence of graphs $\langle \langle G_\alpha; E_\alpha \rangle : \alpha < \text{Ord}\rangle$, there is a homomorphism $\langle G_\alpha; E_\alpha\rangle \to \langle G_\beta; E_\beta\rangle$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in \text{Ord}$ such that $\alpha < \beta$.  This follows from the set-theoretic characterization of VP (see Kanamori, *The Higher Infinite*).  In this characterization, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ arise as the critical point and image of the critical point respectively of an elementary embedding between rank initial segments of the universe.